# CP-ALS Tensor Decomposition

Tags: tensors, tensor-rank, tensor-decomposition

I'm trying to implement CP-ALS (alternating least squares algorithm for canonical polyadic decomposition) tensor rank decomposition, but I cannot find any references for good guesses for the matrix initialization. For all intents and purposes, third-order-tensors should suffice. At this point, I'm almost thinking of just using unit matrices.

I have searched Google and Youtube and Wikipedia in vain, and have been unable to find either pseudocode, reference implementations, or just walk-through examples with real numbers. Am I looking in the wrong places?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good place to look for code examples is [GitHub](https://github.com). For instance, I found [this implementation of CP-ALS](https://github.com/xs-wch/CP_nonneg/blob/master/cpnonneg_als.m) by just searching for the terms "tensor decomposition" in GitHub's search-box function (it was on page 3).

I am not familiar with Alternating Least Squares, let alone the tensor version of it, so I cannot vouch for the accuracy or correctness of the linked code. I think it's a good starting point. At the very least, this is a way for you to find some reference implementations of your algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

In my very limited experience, initializing an ALS approach to CP or PARAFAC is very heuristic. If you have a 3 mode tensor, you could use a [direct trilinear decomposition](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/cem.1180040105) on the data as a starting guess.

If you have an N-dimensional tensor, the factor matrices can be initialized as, $$A^{(n)} = R \ leading\ left\ singular\ vectors\ of \ X_{(n)} $$
as outlined on page 472 in this excellent [review paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/07070111X).

Another method includes intializing CP randomly several times. If all decompositions have the same fit to the data, local minima may not be a problem. Rasmus Bro's N-way Toolbox allows you to use a combination of all of the above, and use the one with the best fit. You should look into what Sandia National Lab's MATLAB Tensor Toolbox does as well.

3 months after it was originally asked, but hopefully this helps someone.